# Как спроектировать стркутуру

Tags: c#, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Нужно написать программу для формирования запросов определенного вида с параметрами.

В конечном счете нужно получать объект, который соответствует строке вида `root.sub?par1=one,par2=two,...`

Параметры `par1` и их значения зависят от того, какому `root.sub` они соответствуют, для каждого свой набор(однако они могут пересекаться)

Кроме того каждый `root` имеет свой набор допустимых `.sub`

Причем в некоторых случаях `.sub` может отсутствовать(хотя этот момент не принципиальный, основная трудность не в нем, но для полноты опишу именно этот случай)

Как организовать такую структуру, чтобы было удобно формировать такие строки, при чем чтобы эта структура знала какие параметры должны соответствовать каждому виду запроса(`root.sub`).

Сейчас я нашел вот такое решение, не довел его до конца, возможно требуется погнать под какой-то паттерн.

Объявляю класс

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract string path { get; }
    protected Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public string asSrt
    {
        get
        {
            string paramSrt = ConvertDictionaryToString(param);
            return String.Format("{0}?{1}", path, paramSrt);
        }
    }
}

Для объектов, в которых path составной:
public abstract class BaseWithSub : Base
{
    protected abstract string mainPath { get; }
    protected abstract string subPath { get; }
    protected override string path
        { 
            get { return String.Format("{0}.{1}", mainPath, subPath); } 
        }
}
```

И создаю конкретный класс:

```
abstract class ConcreteWithSub : BaseWithSub
{
    protected override string mainPath
    { get { return "concreteRoot"; } }

    public class Sub1 : ConcreteWithSub
    {
        protected override string subPath
        { get { return "concreteSub1"; } }

        public bool param1
        { set { param["param1"] = value ? "1" : "0"; } }
        public int param2
        { set { param["param1"] = value.ToString(); } }
    }

    public class Sub2 : ConcreteWithSub
    {
        protected override string MethodSecondName
        { get { return "concreteSub2"; } }

        public int paramA
        { set { param["paramA"] = value.ToString(); } }

        public uint paramB
        { set { param["paramB"] = value.ToString(); } }
    }
}
```

Работаю с ними так:

```
var foo = new ConcreteWithSub.Sub1();
foo.param1 = true;
foo.asSrt(); // "concreteRoot.concreteSub1?param1=1"

var bar = new ConcreteWithSub.Sub2();
bar.paramA = 42;
bar.paramB = 3;
bar.asSrt(); // "concreteRoot.concreteSub2?paramA=42,paramB=3"
```

Такое решение требует создавать кучу классов, у которых по сути будут различаться лишь значения полей.

Возможно следует как-то инкапсулировать процедуру создания запроса в билдере, который будет контролировать процесс формирования, вместо того чтобы пользоваться множественным наследованием.

В общем, хочется услышать критику текущего решения и альтернативные решения(или варианты исправления текущего).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема только в том, что не хочется писать много классов, отличающихся лишь набором полей, то можно использовать [T4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), код будет нагенерирован автоматически.

Но можно попробовать сделать иначе. Сразу определим, что некоторое количество похожих классов написать всё же придётся, потому что иначе не добиться статической типизации параметров запроса, то есть если мы хотим создать свойство конкретного типа для каждого параметра в запросе, то его придётся написать.

Пойдём с конца. В приведённом примере, я увидел, что `bool` значение в результирующей строке представляется в виде чисел `0` и `1`. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что у каждого типа может быть своё представление в результате. Также заметим, что пары `параметр=значение` разделяются запятыми, следовательно ни в названии, ни в значении не может быть запятой. Напишем небольшой интерфейс для форматирования значений и его реализации:

```
public interface IValueFormatter
{
    string Format(object value, CultureInfo culture);
}

public class BoolFormatter
    : IValueFormatter
{
    public string Format(object value, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return (bool)value ? "1" : "0";
    }
}

public class StringFormatter
    : IValueFormatter
{
    public string Format(object value, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return ((string)value).Replace(',', '_');
    }
}

public class DefaultFormatter 
    : IValueFormatter
{
    public string Format(object value, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? value.ToString() : null;
    }
}
```

Конечно, лучше было бы воспользоваться интерфейсом `System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter`, но предположим, что мы не хотим включать в зависимости сборку `PresentationFramework.dll`. Замечу, что в форматтере строкового параметра запятые заменяются на символ подчёркивания, а если значение будет, например, десятичной дробуью, то необходимо будет написать к нему форматтер, используя `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` в качестве аргумента метода `ToString`, чтобы избежать попадания запятой в качестве разделителя целой и дробной части в строковое представление. Я не заводил специфичных форматтеров для целочисленных параметров, потому что работа форматтера по умолчанию меня вполне устраивает. Напишем также вспомогательный класс для форматировани параметра целиком, а не только его значения:

```
public static class QueryParamFormatter
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, IValueFormatter> s_valueFormatters;
    private static readonly IValueFormatter s_defaultFormatter;

    static QueryParamFormatter()
    {
        s_defaultFormatter = new DefaultFormatter();

        s_valueFormatters = new Dictionary<Type, IValueFormatter>();
        s_valueFormatters.Add(typeof(bool?), new BoolFormatter());
        s_valueFormatters.Add(typeof(string), new StringFormatter());
    }

    public static string Format<T>(string paramName, T paramValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("paramName");
        }

        var formatter = GetValueFormatter<T>();
        var valuePresentation = formatter.Format(paramValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (valuePresentation == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return string.Format("{0}={1}", paramName, valuePresentation);
    }
}
```

`bool?` в качестве ключа словаря используется так как, судя по примеру, если параметр не задан, его не надо включать в результат.

Далее, известно, что наборы параметров могут пересекаться, поэтому заведём отдельный тип для представления параметра:

```
public abstract class QueryParam
{
    protected QueryParam(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    protected string ToString<T>(T value)
    {
        return QueryParamFormatter.Format(Name, value);
    }
}
```

Здесь мы ничего не знаем о типе значения параметра, но зато уже знаем как преобразовать его в строку, чем и воспользуемся в наследниках:

```
public class NullableQueryParam<T>
    : QueryParam
    where T : struct
{
    public NullableQueryParam(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }

    public T? Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString(Value);
    }
}

public class QueryParam<T>
    : QueryParam
    where T : class
{
    public QueryParam(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString(Value);
    }
}
```

К сожалению, пришлось написать два очень похожих класса, но зато мы отделили `Nullable<T>` структуры от классов.

Теперь можно описать каждый параметр, который может встречаться в запросе, и поручить их создание фабрике - так мы не ошибёмся при передаче параметра в запрос:

```
public static class ParamsFactory
{
    public static NullableQueryParam<bool> CreateParam1()
    {
        return new NullableQueryParam<bool>("param1");
    }

    public static NullableQueryParam<int> CreateParam2()
    {
        return new NullableQueryParam<int>("param2");
    }

    public static NullableQueryParam<int> CreateParamA()
    {
        return new NullableQueryParam<int>("paramA");
    }

    public static NullableQueryParam<uint> CreateParamB()
    {
        return new NullableQueryParam<uint>("paramB");
    }

    public static QueryParam<string> CreateParamS()
    {
        return new QueryParam<string>("paramS");
    }
}
```

Теперь создадим тип для "подзапроса", то есть той части исходного выражения, которая в результате соответствует части `.sub`. Сразу сделаем ещё и фабрику для более удобного создания подзапросов:

```
public class SubQuery
{
    private readonly string _subPath;

    public SubQuery(string subPath)
    {
        _subPath = subPath ?? string.Empty;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (_subPath != string.Empty ? "." : string.Empty) + _subPath;
    }
}

public static class SubQueryFactory
{
    public static SubQuery CreateSubQuery1()
    {
        return new SubQuery("concreteSub1");
    }

    public static SubQuery CreateSubQuery2()
    {
        return new SubQuery("concreteSub2");
    }

    public static SubQuery CreateNullSubQuery()
    {
        return new SubQuery(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

"Нулевой подзапрос" здесь соответствует ситуации, когда для части `root` не соответствует никакая часть `sub`. Я не стал создавать конкретные реализации `SubQuery` с конкретными наборами `QueryParam`, так как по условиям задачи у разных пар `root.sub` могут быть разные наборых этих параметров.

Теперь создадим базовый класс для запроса и класс запроса с конкретным `root`. Для общности предположим, что у двух разных `root` может быть одинкаковый `sub` и не будем привязывать подзапрос к запросу:

```
public abstract class Query
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly SubQuery _subQuery;

    protected Query(string path, SubQuery subQuery)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        }

        if (subQuery == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("subQuery");
        }

        _path = path;
        _subQuery = subQuery;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var queryParams = GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => typeof(QueryParam).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
            .Select(p => ((QueryParam)p.GetValue(this, null)).ToString())
            .Where(s => s != null)
            .ToList();

        var result = _path + _subQuery;
        if (queryParams.Count != 0)
        {
            result += "?" + string.Join(",", queryParams);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public abstract class RootQuery : Query
{
    protected RootQuery(SubQuery subQuery)
        : base("concreteRoot", subQuery)
    {
    }
}
```

Класс `RootQuery` тут создан только для того, чтобы не передавать в его наследников строку `concreteRoot`. Основная работа происходит в методе `ToString` класса `Query`. Там мы рефлексией находим все свойства типа (на самом деле наследника `Query`), которые можно привести к `QueryParam`, и вызываем у каждого `ToString`, получая пары `параметр=значение`, объединяем их через запятую и конкатенируем с выражением "запрос.подзапрос?".

Теперь осталось только создать наследников класс `RootQuery` и добавить в них конкретные параметры запроса:

```
public class RootQuerySub1 : RootQuery
{
    public RootQuerySub1()
        : base(SubQueryFactory.CreateSubQuery1())
    {
        Param1 = ParamsFactory.CreateParam1();
        Param2 = ParamsFactory.CreateParam2();
    }

    public NullableQueryParam<bool> Param1 { get; private set; }
    public NullableQueryParam<int> Param2 { get; private set; }
}

public class RootQuerySub2 : RootQuery
{
    public RootQuerySub2()
        : base(SubQueryFactory.CreateSubQuery2())
    {
        ParamA = ParamsFactory.CreateParamA();
        ParamB = ParamsFactory.CreateParamB();
    }

    public NullableQueryParam<int> ParamA { get; private set; }
    public NullableQueryParam<uint> ParamB { get; private set; }
}

public class RootQueryNullSub : RootQuery
{
    public RootQueryNullSub()
        : base(SubQueryFactory.CreateNullSubQuery())
    {
        Param1 = ParamsFactory.CreateParam1();
        ParamS = ParamsFactory.CreateParamS();
    }

    public NullableQueryParam<bool> Param1 { get; private set; }
    public QueryParam<string> ParamS { get; private set; }
}
```

Работает всё это так. Тестовое приложение с кодом:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var q1 = new RootQuerySub1();
        q1.Param1.Value = true;
        Console.WriteLine(q1.ToString());

        var q2 = new RootQuerySub2();
        q2.ParamA.Value = 42;
        q2.ParamB.Value = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(q2.ToString());

        var q3 = new RootQueryNullSub();
        q3.Param1.Value = false;
        q3.ParamS.Value = "param,Value";
        Console.WriteLine(q3.ToString());
    }
}
```

Выводит следующий результат:

```
concreteRoot.concreteSub1?param1=1
concreteRoot.concreteSub2?paramA=42,paramB=3
concreteRoot?param1=0,paramS=param_Value
```

При этом все условия начальной задачи соблюдены, добавлять новые запросы и новые параметры достаточно просто, как и параметры новых типов. Вся типизация у нас статическая и, если использовать фабрики, то ошибиться в имени или типе значения параметра достаточно сложно. Естественно, будет комбинаторный взрыв, если попытаться создать все возможные запросы, но, увы, при существующей постановке задачи (у каждой пары `root.sub` может быть свой набор параметров) это неизбежно.

P.S. При этом всё это смахивает на один большой велосипед, поэтому сначала я всё-таки рассмотрел бы возможности кодогенерации посредством T4.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, попробуйте через reflection.

Например, так можно передать объект любого типа и выдать строковое преобразование полей и их значений:

```
    public static string ToStringFromFields(this object fromObject, string splitter = " ")
    {
        if (fromObject == null) return "null";

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var propertyList = fromObject.GetType().GetFields();
        var valueList = propertyList.Select(x => new { x.Name, Value = x.GetValue(fromObject) });
        foreach (var propertyInfo in valueList)
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}{2}", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.Value, splitter);
        if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Remove(sb.Length - length, length);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Дальше можно как угодно развивать механизм: добавлять пользовательские атрибуты, особую обработку классов родителей, задавать шаблоны преобразования в строку...

В вашем решении нужно много работы делать вручную и ничего не забывать. Накладываются ограничения на родительские классы.